# wget 5xx error code handling

Tags: wget

I'm executing a shell script that utilizes wget to retrieve data from the web. I'm wondering if there's a way to instruct wget to terminate the process immediately upon encountering a 500 error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess wget doesn't have a way to handle any errors at this point :( that's kind of sucks, unfortinetly curl won't work for me, but if something I think curl's way of handeling it would be the closest so to speak solution...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check our `curl` as it's a bit more robust especially when handling things of that nature.

Now I don't know off the top of my head how to do what you want however `curl` has certain exit codes for certain events. This one may be of interest to you:

> 22
>
> HTTP page not retrieved. The requested url was not found or returned another error with the >HTTP error code being 400 or above. This return code only appears if -f/--fail is used.

I would recommend checking out the [curl man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: I can't use curl, I need to use wget.